# Equivalence of Landau notation: $ f(n) = \Omega (n^{1+\epsilon}) \Leftrightarrow n=o(f(n))?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be strictly positive functions, the Omega Landau notation 
$$f(n) = \Omega\left(g(n)\right)$$
 is commonly used to mean 
$$  \exists\; K,n_0\!>\!0 \;\mathrm{s.t.}\;  f(n)  >K  g(n) ,\;n>n_0.$$
Similarly, the little $o$ Landau notation 
$$f(n) = o\left(g(n)\right)$$
is used to mean
$$  \exists\; n_0\!>\!0 \;\mathrm{s.t.}\;  f(n) < \epsilon g(n) ,\;n>n_0,\;\epsilon>0.$$

**My question is the following**:

**Does
$$f(n) = \Omega (n^{1+\epsilon}) \Leftrightarrow n=o(f(n))?$$**

I can see that 
$$f(n) = \Omega (n^{1+\epsilon}) \Rightarrow n=o(f(n))$$
  since $\exists \; K,\;n>n_0$ s.t.
\begin{equation}
 \frac{n}{f(n)}\leq \frac{n}{K n^{1+\epsilon}} \to 0.
\end{equation}
 I'm not sure how to prove the converse statement; however, intuitively it seems that if $n=o(f(n))$ (i.e., $f(n)$ grows faster than $n$), it  must be $\Omega(n^{1+\epsilon}).$

Comment: How about $f(n)=n\log n$?

Comment: @ karakusc $n\log n = \Omega (n^{1+\epsilon})$, isn't it?

Comment: Definitely not. If $n\log n = \Omega(n^{1+\epsilon}$, then there would exist a positive constant $c$ such that $(n\log n)/n^{1+\epsilon} > c$ for infinitely many $n$. But $(n\log n)/n^{1+\epsilon}$ tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: By the way, it's also false that $f(n) = \Omega(n^{1+\epsilon})$ implies $n=o(f(n))$, because the $\Omega$ statement just means that an inequality is achieved for infinitely many $n$, while $o$ requires an inequality for all large $n$. For example, $f(n) = n^{1+(-1)^n}$ is $\Omega(n^2)$ even, but it's not true that $n=o(f(n))$.

Comment: Ah, I see that you wrote a definition of $\Omega$ that differs from the one in my previous comment. I'm pretty sure that my definition is the standard one, so you might want to check your sources for the definition of $\Omega$ you want to use.

Comment: @GregMartin Actually, you might want to check *your* sources for the definition of Omega (I have never seen it defined otherwise than what the OP says).

Comment: Probably there are different conventions in different fields. I'm in analytic number theory, wherein $\Omega(\cdot)$ is literally the negation of $o(\cdot)$. See for example page 4 of Montgomery and Vaughan's *Multiplicative Number Theory I*.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the reference. This is most annoying, I must say.